# Automatically reconnect client socket on server shutdown?

Tags: python, sockets

So, I've had a problem this morning that I couldn't find any posted answers yet. Basically, I wanted to have my Python client to reconnect everytime the server shuts down.

My previous code looks like this

```
 def fire(self):
     self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     self.s.settimeout(5)

     while (self.connected):
         # create the transmission_struct class

         msg = transmission_struct(self.stream, self.CHUNK, self.rate)

         # create the Filestream packet

         packet1 = msg.structure_msg_fls()

         # create the decision packet

         packet2 = msg.structure_msg_stm()

         # send, first the decision packet
         self.s.sendall(packet2)

         # send the whole packet one by one

         for i in range(len(packet1)):
             self.s.sendall(packet1[i])

         # timestamp for debugging purposes

         ts = time.time()
         timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
         print(timestamp + " size of data sent is " + str(len(packet1)) +
               " size of decision is " + str(len(packet2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I implemented the reconnection logic through `try` and `exception` blocks and a recursion in the attempt function.

```
 def fire(self):
     self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     self.s.settimeout(5)
     self.attempt_connect()

     while (self.connected):
         # create the transmission_struct class

         msg = transmission_struct(self.stream, self.CHUNK, self.rate)

         # create the Filestream packet

         packet1 = msg.structure_msg_fls()

         # create the decision packet

         packet2 = msg.structure_msg_stm()

         try:
             # send, first the decision packet
             self.s.sendall(packet2)

             # send the whole packet one by one

             for i in range(len(packet1)):
                 self.s.sendall(packet1[i])

             # timestamp for debugging purposes

             ts = time.time()
             timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
             print(timestamp + " size of data sent is " + str(len(packet1)) + " size of decision is " + str(len(packet2)))

         except socket.error as e:
             print(e.errno)
             self.connected = False
             print("Attempting to connect...")
             self.close_open_new_socket()
             time.sleep(1)
             continue

         except IOError as e:
             print(e.errno)
             self.close_open_new_socket()
             continue

         except KeyboardInterrupt:
             self.s.close()

         finally:
             self.attempt_connect()

 def attempt_connect(self):
     while (self.connected is False):
         try:
             self.result = self.s.connect((self.host, self.port))
             if (self.result == None):
                 self.connected = True
             else:
                 self.connected = False
         except socket.error as e:
             errorcode = e[0]
             print(errorcode)
             if (errorcode == 56):
                 self.connected = True
                 time.sleep(1)
                 continue
             elif(errorcode == 22):
                 self.connected = False
                 print("attempting to reconnect...")
                 # adding recursive call to attempt connect
                 # after socket is broken
                 self.close_open_new_socket()
                 time.sleep(1)
                 continue
             elif (errorcode == 61):
                 self.connected = False
                 print("Server not up, waiting for server and reconnecting...")
                 time.sleep(1)
                 continue
             elif (errorcode == 32):
                 self.connected = False
                 print("Server down, attempting to reconnect...")
                 time.sleep(1)
                 continue
             else:
                 self.connected = False
                 time.sleep(1)
                 continue

 def close_open_new_socket(self):
     self.s.close()
     self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     self.s.settimeout(5)
     self.attempt_connect()
```

Comment: This worked for you? I don't see how. There isn't any recursion... and since you set connected to false, its just going to fall out of the loop.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. About the recursion, I called close_open_new_socket which contains attempt_connect inside attempt_connect.